# What can we do about users adding long/confusing bounty comments to questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'm referring to this question with a +50 bounty posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250892/phpspreadsheet-get-raw-string-value-for-d-m-y-dates-instead-of-being-converted)

I came across this today - it looks like a very low rep user (35 reputation) added a +50 bounty and dumped a long code snippet with it.

[image: img1]

This is practically unreadable (at least to me) and is completely unnecessary - is there any limit to what can be entered in the bounty comment box? Can we prevent giant code snippets like the one above? Could we perhaps put a minimum reputation on adding a custom comment to a bounty?

Comment: point and laugh

Comment: Just mod flag. I don’t think it happens often enough as to devise a catch all solution. It’s exceptional. Let our exception handlers handle it.

Comment: Just please tell me Zalgo text doesn't work in the bounty box...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I removed the bounty for now. Assuming good faith, that was probably an accident.

I agree that this seems to happen rarely enough to just handle it with mod-flags on a case by case basis, no further formal restrictions required.